# Cloudfoundry URL(smile-spring.coludfoundry.com) Inaccessible with following Status

Tags: cloud-foundry

C:>vmc stats smile
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Getting stats for smile... OK

instance   cpu    memory         disk

## 0         0.5%   198.2K of 1G   54.6M of 2G

Answer (score 0):

The 404 is coming from Tomcat which means connections are being forwarded correctly. Looking at the location the 404 is coming from;

/WEB-INF/views/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp.jsp

one can only assume there is something suspect with the way requests are being routed with in the application itself.